# How UIActivityViewController title and description works?

Tags: ios, swift, customization, title, uiactivityviewcontroller

How the title and description parts of the header on UIActivityViewController works by default on iOS and other platforms? In cases, where there's no customization and any other works done to set them, how these 2 elements are generated by the system.

There can be multiple scenarios according to the type of element that's being shared and their related attributes. So, understanding this default mechanisms of the system requires trial and error attempts to figure them out. It would be better to have a common system design of it.

Answer (score 0):

For **iOS13+** it is possible with LPLinkMetadata for UIActivityViewController. Check this tutorial for full info: [Composing Rich Link Previews Using LinkPresentation in Swift](https://richkolasa.netlify.app/posts/2019/07/composing-rich-link-previews-using-linkpresentation-in-swift/)